# Accessing a local variable inside an inner class

Tags: java, android

I have the following code inside my **MainActivity.java** file:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static String nodeAddress = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Search For The NodeMCU On The Connected Network
        UPnPDiscovery.discoveryDevices(this, new UPnPDiscovery.OnDiscoveryListener() {
            @Override
            public void OnStart() {
                Log.d("UPnP Discovery", "Started Device Discovery");
            }

            @Override
            public void OnFoundNewDevice(UPnPDevice device) {
                Log.d("UPnP Discovery", "Found UPnP Device " + device.getManufacturer());
                try {
                    if (device.getManufacturer().equals("Nobody")) {
                        MainActivity.nodeAddress = device.getHostAddress();
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.e("ERROR", ex.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void OnFinish(HashSet<UPnPDevice> devices) {
                Log.d("UPnP Discovery", "Finished Searching");
                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.connectionStatus);
                tv.setText(MainActivity.nodeAddress);
            }

            @Override
            public void OnError(Exception e) {
                Log.d("UPnP Discovery", "Error While Searching For Devices");
            }
        });
        Log.d("IoT Project", "Value of nodeAddress = " + MainActivity.nodeAddress);
        // Channel 1 Event Listeners
        final Button ch1OFF = findViewById(R.id.channel1Off);
        final Button ch1ON = findViewById(R.id.channel1On);
        final Button ch1SENSOR = findViewById(R.id.channel1Sensor);

        // Channel 2 Event Listeners
        final Button ch2OFF = findViewById(R.id.channel2Off);
        final Button ch2ON = findViewById(R.id.channel2On);
        final Button ch2SENSOR = findViewById(R.id.channel2Sensor);

        // Setting Up OkHTTP To Send Requests Over The Network
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        String ch1OffUrl = "http://" + MainActivity.nodeAddress +"/alwaysOFFOne";
        String ch2OffUrl = "http://" + MainActivity.nodeAddress +"/alwaysOFFTwo";
        String ch1OnUrl = "http://" + MainActivity.nodeAddress +"/alwaysONOne";
        String ch2OnUrl = "http://" + MainActivity.nodeAddress +"/alwaysONTwo";
        String ch1SensorUrl = "http://" + MainActivity.nodeAddress +"/sensorModeOne";
        String ch2SensorUrl = "http://" + MainActivity.nodeAddress +"/sensorModeTwo";

        // Setting Event Listeners For Channel 1
        ch1OFF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("IoT Project", "Sending Request To " + ch1OffUrl);
                // Building The OkHTTP Request Instance
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(ch1OffUrl)
                        .build();

                // Making The HTTP Call Using The Client Instance
                client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            String myResponse = response.body().string();

                            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.connectionStatus);
                                    tv.setText("Channel 1 OFF");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I am trying to create a variable called **nodeAddress** outside of the UPnP Discovery inner class, and assign it a value inside the inner class so I can use it outside aswell, like in the onclick events.

However the assignment is only scoped to the inner class, outside of the inner class it stays as null and never works!

Comment: Well after reading your post and then looking at the code i'm quite amazed you dumped that much of irrelevant code. I expected ten code lines about to demonstrate your problem. Maybe a few more. Please redo.

Comment: You are accessing `nodeAddress` sequentially where as its get initialized by a callback .

Answer (score 1):

It seems that happens, because you're trying to get the value in `MainActivity`, before setting it in `OnFoundNewDevice`.

In other word, the `OnFoundNewDevice` is getting called, sometime after this log message that you have in your activity:

```
Log.d("IoT Project", "Value of nodeAddress = " + MainActivity.nodeAddress);
```

after the `OnFoundNewDevice` gets called, you can use the nodeAddress value on your `ClickListeners`.

Comment: @SaadSawash You need to wait till the OnFoundNewDevice function gets called. then proceed.

Comment: It depends on ux of your application. 1 way is to show a loading till the OnFoundNewDevice gets called. another is to check the nodeAddress value before using it and if its null, show a toast for user to wait till you collect data. there are many ways to handle that.